# Size comparisons (circumference/square perimeter) etc

Tags: java

3 diffrent `classes` 1 for handling `Circle` isntances ,1 for `Square` instances and the 3rd for `comparrisons` between them(`main`) . In the `main` function i find the `circle` (between `c1..c4`) and `square` (between `s1...s5`) and print the `biggest circumference and area of them respectively`.[so circle-circle and square-square comparison]

***!!!! NOTE :*** Only the ones with the biggers radius or sides have the biggest circumference or area , so i only use `r` and `a` for comparisons.i dont know if its possible to return `this` if i use the `area`/`circumference` method(no , cause then i will only handle numbers ?).Correct me please.

Now i want to print the characteristics(x,y,r/a) of the `geometric shape` (circle/square) with the `biggest perimeter`. How can i do this ? Where do i compare?New class?[square-circle comparison]

```
public class Circle {
        public double x,y,r;
        public double circumference() {
            return 2*(3.14)*r;
        }
        public double area() {
            return 3.14*r*r;
        }
        public Circle bigger(Circle c){
            if(c.r>r) return c; else return this; 
        } 
        public Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
            this.x=x; 
            this.y=y; 
            this.r=r;
        }
    }

public class Square {
    public double x,y,a;
    public double perimeter() {
        return 4*a;
    }
    public double area() {
        return a*a;
    }
    public Square bigger(Square s){
        if(s.a>a) return s; else return this; 
    } 
    public Square(double x, double y, double a) {
        this.x=x; 
        this.y=y; 
        this.a=a;
    }
}

public class CircleAndSquareTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(1.0,0.0,2.0);
        Circle c3 = new Circle(0.0,2.0,4.0);
        Circle c4 = new Circle(1.0,3.0,1.0);
        Circle cb = c1.bigger(c2).bigger(c3).bigger(c4);
        System.out.println("The circle with the biggest circumference has:\n");
        System.out.println("x-axis value: " + cb.x + " y-axis value: " + cb.y + " radius: " + cb.r+"\n");

        Square s1 = new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        Square s2 = new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        Square s3 = new Square(0.0,0.0,5.0);
        Square s4 = new Square(4.0,2.0,2.0);
        Square s5 = new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        Square sb = s1.bigger(s2).bigger(s3).bigger(s4).bigger(s5);
        System.out.println("The square with the biggest area has:\n");
        System.out.println("x-axis value: " + sb.x + " y-axis value: " + 
        sb.y + " side: " + sb.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create a Comparator for each of your shapes, add them to a collection and use the Collections.max method to get the largest.

Comment: Dont want to do it like that . Im a begginer

Comment: Why don't you expose a `perimeter` function? You will then need to have an interface `Shape` providing this method and implemented by `Square` and `Circle`. Additionally you can use `Comparable<Shape>` to allow built-in libraries to order your objects.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez Is it easy to type somthing for me?This is something i can understand but want some help. About the interface use ,not the other.

Comment: Can i reach you in a few hours again?I will post what i did.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept. Does that mean that your questions are all answered?

Comment: i didnt accept.upvoted maybe? dunno.. i have one last thing. how would a complete noob approach this? without instances etc. just how my code is with hardcoded numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it using Comparators and the Collections class to find the max value. This is untested but it should do what you want. Note I'm using static inner classes here but they can be standard classes defined in their own file if needs be - this is just for the purpose of creating a quick answer.

```
public interface Shape {
    double getPerimeter();
    double getArea();
}

public static class PerimeterComparator implements Comparator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shape a, Shape b) {
        return Double.compare(a.getPerimeter(), b.getPerimeter());
    }
}

public static class AreaComparator implements Comparator<Shape> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Shape a, Shape b) {
        return Double.compare(a.getArea(), b.getArea());
    }
}

public static class Circle implements Shape {
    private final double x, y, r;

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (3.14) * r;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 3.14 * r * r;
    }

    public Circle(double x, double y, double r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }
}

public static class Square implements Shape{
    private final double x, y, a;

    @Override
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 4 * a;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return a * a;
    }

    public Square(double x, double y, double a) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.a = a;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getA() {
        return a;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Circle> circles = new ArrayList<>();
    circles.add(new Circle(0.0,0.0,1.0));
    circles.add(new Circle(1.0,0.0,2.0));
    circles.add(new Circle(0.0,2.0,4.0));
    circles.add(new Circle(1.0,3.0,1.0));

    Circle largestCircle = Collections.max(circles, new PerimeterComparator());

    System.out.println("The circle with the biggest circumference has:\n");
    System.out.println("x-axis value: " + largestCircle.getX() + " y-axis value: " + largestCircle.getY() + " radius: " + largestCircle.getPerimeter() +"\n");

    List<Square> squares = new ArrayList<>();
    squares.add(new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0));
    squares.add(new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0));
    squares.add(new Square(0.0,0.0,5.0));
    squares.add(new Square(4.0,2.0,2.0));
    squares.add(new Square(0.0,0.0,1.0));

    Square largestSquare = Collections.max(squares, new PerimeterComparator());

    System.out.println("The square with the biggest area has:\n");
    System.out.println("x-axis value: " + largestSquare.getX() + " y-axis value: " + largestSquare.getY() + " side: " + largestSquare.getA());

    shapes.addAll(circles);
    shapes.addAll(squares);

    Shape largestPerimeter = Collections.max(shapes, new PerimeterComparator());
    Shape largestArea      = Collections.max(shapes, new AreaComparator());

    System.out.printf("\nThe shape with the biggest perimeter is a %s and has has: a perimeter of: %f\n", largestPerimeter.getClass().getSimpleName(), largestPerimeter.getPerimeter());
    System.out.printf("The shape with the biggest area is a %s and has has: an area of: %f\n", largestArea.getClass().getSimpleName(), largestArea.getArea());
}
```

Comment: i cant use that i have no idea about arays. How can i compare square with circle and how will making an interface (in my code) help the situation. I learned what interface is , diffrences with abstract etc etc but the use here..

Comment: It uses an `ArrayList` which is not the same as an array. It is simply an ordered collection of objects, and unlike an array the size is not fixed. I suggest you look at the List and Map types as they are widely used in Java.

Comment: Back to the interface question because they both have the same interface they can be compared. If, for example, you wanted to find the shape with the largest perimeter, you could add all the squares and circles to a `List<Shape>` (the interface, rather than the concrete type) then using the Collections.max method on that, using the `PerimeterComparator`.

Comment: ok i understood the arays . lets say i do the interface part  . How is it possible to compare without using arrays (the way my code is but only with interface addition)?

Comment: In a nut shell, you wouldn't really... If you don't use a collection of some sort, you would have to change it every time you wanted to count and sort some shapes which violates the open close principal. Using a dynamic collection and extracting the comparison logic into it's own method would be the best approach, hard coding would be the worst and I would suggest it's something you should avoid at all costs. I don't know why you're avoiding arrays and collections but you'll need to get over that fear if you're serious about programming in Java.

Comment: lets say i choose the way using hardcoded things, what would the command be for the comparison or is more needed from me?

Comment: If you choose to do it that way, you're making your life deliberately difficult and looking up how to use a `Comparator` in an `if` statement is the least of your worries!

Comment: what is that Comperator u are refereing to?Is It soemthing i create or something already defined?

Comment: The `AreaComparator` and `PerimeterComparator` from my example above are `Comparators`.

Comment: one more thing. wait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183423/discussion-between-lowspacetop-and-jste89).

Answer (score 1):

Start by declaring a base interface, maybe called Shape that defines a method *getPerimeterLength()* for example.

Have all your shape classes implement that interface, and the corresponding method(s).

Now, a Square is also a Shape, and so is a Circle. Then you could put all these objects into an array of Shape. You iterate that array, and identify that entry with the maximum perimeter length. Then you simply call *toString()* on that object. Because you also overwrite the *toString()* method in all your classes to print the (different!) details each class has internally.

Comment: I dont want to use arrays(unless you define something else as an array?). I can handle them(if they are same as c) , but i dont want to. I like that interface part much much more but i need some code (like ,is it a new class etcetc.).

Comment: Wrong: the purpose of the toString() method is exactly that: to create a specific string containing all information about the object behind it. You absolutely do not want to have *other* code build information by pulling ten details from inside some object. And as written in my comment above: this is really basic stuff, with many examples in books or tutorials. You don't need me to give you that code. You can research this yourself, and in the end, you will have learned 10 things more compared to me doing that for you.

Comment: i corrected the string from my comment u say it to late though. my bad initially. will read and be back (hope so are you ;))

Comment: Will i need to create an instance of the interface(just throwing that out)?I need to compare Circle with Square. I also need to print which specificly has the largest perimeter ,this can oly be done with `this` keyword right?

Comment: You can't create an instance of an `interface` - an `interface` is essentially just a contract - any class that implements the interface must match the the interface in terns of the methods it provides. You can, however, use an interface as a type when you're declaring a variable (I.e. `List e = new ArrayList();`- `List` is an Interface, `ArrayList` is a class that implements List).

Comment: The `this` keyword is used when you need to explicitly refer to a non-static field or method within an instance of a class. You generally do that in constructors or setter methods when the method input parameter has the same name as a field within the class. So for what you're doing, no you don't.